# How can I calculate a robotic arm's maximum reach?

Tags: robotics

I have the **Fanuc robotic M-2000iA/2300** data sheet in which it is being told that its maximum reach is **3734 mm** and its payload capacity is **2300 kg**, so how is its maximum reach being calculated and in respect to which axis?

Also, what will the load capacity be at that point?

[image: Fanuc Robotic M-2000iA/2300]

[Datasheet](https://www.fanuc.eu/%7E/media/files/pdf/products/robots/robots-datasheets-en/m-2000ia/datasheet%20m-2000ia-2300.pdf)

Comment: The jelly-bean shape, inside which is written *"Motion range of the J5 axis center"* demonstrates the accessible movement range of the arm.  Naturally, the maximum horizontal extent will be at the height of the J2 axis (1300mm above the base) when the arm is fully extended.  This is a big and dangerous robot to be shopping for if you can't answer these types of questions on your own... consider making use of a consultant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you notice in the datasheet, for the weight it says that it is at the wrist.

Having said that, usually there isn't any standard calculation method for robotic arms. It is basically striking a balance between:

- maximizing the load (to satisfy marketing)
- minimizing the load (to make the legal team stop complaining about possible lawsuits).

There was one notable exception I have had the pleasure to encounter (it was not on a robotic arm, but on a [Stewart platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewart_platform)) that takes the time/effort to provide software that calculates the allowable load at any given position in space. Probably there are more like that.

Answer (score 3):

Total reach is usually the straight line length of each member added together, do work centre to centre.

The manufacturer will specify the total load at a spcific configuration so check the detail.

Comment: Okay but in some cases they don't give max reach but they give all the dimension of each axis so I have to add all that axis so that I can get max reach

Comment: @SiddhMistry isn’t that what I put in paragraph 1?

Comment: yes I just want to know the formula or some calculation to find it out I'm just a fresher in this field so if you think that you can help me out then thank you other wise its okay